# How to create a nested list in Libreoffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice

I would like to create a list that looks as follows:

1. Main item 1
   1a. Sub item 1a
   1b. Sub item 1b
2. Main item 2 
   2a. Sub item 2a
   2b. Sub item 2b 
   2c. Sub item 2c
3. Main item 3 
   3a. Sub item 3a

Comment: For those that aren't attached to this formatting but are wondering why Libreoffice isn't using subcategories, Libreoffice calls this an "Outline List" style. On my system the toolbar only has a "Bulleted List" and "Numbered List" styles. I ended up customizing the toolbar to add the "Outline List" button. After using this style you'll be able to use <Tab> as @Mandar describes.

Answer (score 5):

The nested list can be created similarly in LibreOffice Writer.

In LibreOffice Writer, type relevant text. In this answer, I have typed everything: main items and sub items in respective rows. The sublevels can be changed later.

```
Main item 1
Sub item 1a
Sub item 1b
Main item 2
Sub item 2a
Sub item 2b
Sub item 2c
Main item 3
Sub item 3a
```

After finish typing, highlight those text. Open the context menu by right-click or the reverse, then select **Bullets and Numbering...** (or from menu bar: **Format > Bullets and Numbering...**)

In "Bullets and Numbering" window, do the following:

1. In **Numbering** tab, select `Number 1. 2. 3.` (from top-left, the second option)
2. In **Customize** tab, under **Level**: `2` and under **Numbering**, select Number: `a, b, c, ...` and change Show sublevels: `2`
3. In **Position** tab, under **Level**: `2` and under **Position & Spacing**, change Tab stop at: `0.35 "` and change Indent at: `0.35 "` similarly
4. Click **OK** to finish

Following above steps will give a simple, one-level list:

```
1. Main item 1
2. Sub item 1a
3. Sub item 1b
4. Main item 2
5. Sub item 2a
6. Sub item 2b
7. Sub item 2c
8. Main item 3
9. Sub item 3a
```

Finally, do tabbing: Place a cursor at the beginning of text "Sub item", then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> key once. Repeat tabbing for other instances. This will realign and renumber `2.` to `1.a.` and so forth.

Tabbing all "Sub item" will give the nested list.

```
1. Main item 1
    1.a. Sub item 1a
    1.b. Sub item 1b
2. Main item 2
    2.a. Sub item 2a
    2.b. Sub item 2b
    2.c. Sub item 2c
3. Main item 3
    3.a. Sub item 3a
```

Some discrepancies:

- The indentation in step 3 is to ensure the sub items are aligned properly when sublevels option is more than 1. The default alignment is off for some reason.
- The actual result `1.a.` in this answer is slightly different from the desired result `1a.` in the question. This is probably a limitation or a feature to distinguish the numbering for each level in LibreOffice. The period in between *can not be removed* based on my testing.

Tested with LibreOffice 5.4 on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible. Just press <kbd>Tab</kbd> after coming to next line.

*Example:*

1. This is my first bullet point (Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>)

   1. If you press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, you'll get a subpoint

Comment: Alas mine are not indented.